# The number of non-trivial ring homomorohism from $Z_{20}$ to$ Z_{44}$

Tags: ring-homomorphism

Consider $Z_{20}$ and $Z_{44}$ as ring modulo $20$ and $44$ respectively.Then number of non-trivial ring homomorohism from $Z_{20}$ to $Z_{44}$ is?

Comment: Well, $f(1)=1$, so $f(1+1)=f(1)+f(1)=1+1$, $\ldots$

Comment: Generally, visitors to this site like to know what a questioner already knows about the field, and what ideas have been tried, successfully or unsuccessfully.

Comment: Ring homomorphisms usually send 1 to 1. If that is the case for you, then there is at most one ring homomorphism

Answer (score 1):

The number of ring homomorphism from $Z_m$ to $Z_n$ is $2^{W(n)-W(n/g.c.d(m,n))}$ where $W(n)$  is number of prime divisor of $n$.
so number of ring homomorphism is 2..out of 2 1 is trivial homomorphism so 1 is non-trivial homomorphism..